# Still error display: Missing required parameter

Tags: laravel

I facing the issue **Missing required parameter for [Route: search.customer] [URI: agency/{slug}] [Missing parameter: slug]**

Here is below my code

```
Route::get('/agency/{slug}', [SearchController::class, 'listing'])->name('search.customer');

@if ($agents->isNotEmpty())
     @foreach ($agents as $value)
         <a href="{{ route('search.customer', ['slug'=>$value->agency_slug]) }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn_hover">View More</a>
     @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: Check the value of `$value->agency_slug`, if it's null then a `Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException` about missing route parameter will be thrown. You can check the value using `dd($value)` in the controller

Comment: Yes, I checked `$value->agency_slug` this value give me null and this issue is solved now. Thank u for helping